# What does it mean the color in the column "installed (available)" in the Yast2 software management section?

Tags: linux, package-management, opensuse

I'm using openSUSE 11.3. 
In the Yast2's module: Software Management, in the search tab, there is a column called: "Installed (Available)", It usually shows the current installed version of the package, but sometimes its blue, red or most of the times black.

Someone can tell me what does the color mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the colour coding indicating status of the selected package

- Blue: There is a newer version of your installed package available.
- Red: The package that you have installed is newer than the available version.
- Black: The package that is installed is the same as the available version.